# Have flyspell mark all misspelled words even those not written during the current session

Tags: emacs, flyspell

When I active flyspell, `M-x flyspell-mode`, it marks misspelled words as I write them but it does not mark any misspelled words in the buffer that I have not written during current session. How can I make it so that flyspell also marks misspelled word not written during the current session?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you can manually do:

```
M-x flyspell-buffer
```

If you want this to happen every time you turn on `flyspell-mode`, you can add this to your .emacs:

```lisp
(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook 'flyspell-buffer)
```

Comment: How can I make it so that `flyspell-buffer` automatically happens when I turn `flyspell-mode` on in certain modes, e.g. if I want to  enable flyspell automatically in AUCTeX and have it mark misspelled words in the whole buffer?

Comment: @N.N. The hook will turn it on for all modes, if you want just specific modes, change the hook to be something like, (lambda () (when (member major-mode '(auctex-mode other-mode-i-want)) (flyspell-buffer)))